# Insert while loop values to tkinter magic window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a code to create a "magic window" in python.
It should shows title, time and news. 
I took news with function `newz` to loop (it should show the news on-by-on in Tkinter window)
I tried to insert it into tkinter `label` but it doesn't work(it just doesn't appear, but when I insert plain text to label it works), how could I do it? Here is the whole code with time functions and news function + tkinter

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import feedparser
import json
from time import sleep
import time
import os

startupscreen = tk.Tk()
startupscreen.title('Magic Mirror: Python Mod')
welcometext = tk.Label(startupscreen, font = ('caviar dreams', 40), bg='black', fg='white')
startupscreen.configure(background='black')
startupscreen.overrideredirect(True)
welcometext.config(text='日本')
welcometext.pack(side=LEFT, padx= 120, pady=80)
# Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
windowWidth = startupscreen.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = startupscreen.winfo_reqheight()
# Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
positionRight = int(startupscreen.winfo_screenwidth()/3 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(startupscreen.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)

# Positions the window in the center of the page.
startupscreen.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))
startupscreen.update()



decrypt = list()
global iteration
global timecount
global repull
global sleep
iteration = 0
timecount = 0
repull = 0
sleep = 0

# main window
while True:
    def tick(time1=''):
        time2 = time.strftime("%H")
        if time2 != time1:
            time1 = time2
            clock_frame.config(text=time2)
        clock_frame.after(200, tick)

    def tickk(time3=''):
        time4 = time.strftime(":%M:%S")
        if time4 != time3:
            time3 = time4
            clock_frame2.config(text=time4)
        clock_frame2.after(200, tickk)

    def newz():
        url = 'https://news.google.com/rss?hl=ja&gl=JP&ceid=JP:ja'
        d = feedparser.parse(url)
        news = list()

        for i, entry in enumerate(d.entries, 1):
            p = entry.published_parsed
            sortkey = "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d" % (p.tm_year, p.tm_mon, p.tm_mday, p.tm_hour, p.tm_min, p.tm_sec)

            tmp = {

                "title": entry.title,
            #"link": entry.link,

                "sortkey": sortkey
                }

            news.append(tmp)

        news = sorted(news, key=lambda x: x['sortkey'])


        myDict = {}

        for d in news:
            c = d['title']
            myDict[c] = myDict.get(c,0)+1
            frequency = myDict.keys()
        frequency = list(frequency)
        for x in range(len(frequency)):
            print (frequency[x])
            x += 1


    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Mirror')
    lab = Label(root, text=" 日本", font = ('', 40), bg='black', fg='white')
    lab.pack(anchor=SW, fill=X, padx=45)
    masterclock = tk.Label(root)
    masterclock.pack(anchor=NW, fill=X, padx=45)
    masterclock.configure(background='black')
    clock_frame = tk.Label(root, font = ('caviar dreams', 130), bg='black', fg='white')
    clock_frame.pack(in_=masterclock, side=LEFT)
    clock_frame2 = tk.Label(root, font = ('caviar dreams', 70), bg='black', fg='white')
    clock_frame2.pack(in_=masterclock, side=LEFT, anchor = N, ipady=15)
    newstitle = tk.Label(root, font = ('caviar dreams', 30), bg='black', fg='white')
    newstitle.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W, fill=X)
    source = tk.Label(root, font = ('caviar dreams', 20), bg='black', fg='white')
    source.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W, fill=X)


    tick()
    tickk()
    newz() #here it doesnt work

    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    root.configure(background='black')
    startupscreen.destroy()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what means "doesn't work" ? Do you get error message ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas no it just doesn't appear, but when I insert plain text to label it works

Comment: did you try to use `print()` in function which should change text  - to test if this function is executed ?

Comment: did you use `print()` to check if you get anything from internet ?

Comment: @furas, Yes, it gets news from the Internet when I just print it

Comment: inside `news()` I don't see code which changes text in Label

Comment: If I put `source.config(text="some text")` in `newz()` then I see "some text" in window.

Comment: I don't see `root.after(1000, newz)` in `newz()` so it will run only once.

Comment: @furas sorry for my `questions`, my knowledges about Tkinter are very shallow, I added it to `newz()` as you said but it doesnt shows anything

Comment: what did you add ? in which place did you add ? show it in code in question.

Comment: IN QUESTION!!! in comment it is useless

Comment: I posted it there

Comment: in question, not in place for answers.

Comment: you have to use `source.config(text="some text")` and `root.after(1000, newz)`  inside function `newz()`,

Comment: thanks! Going to look at it how to insert it to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you want to display but you have to use

```
    source.config(text="some text")
    root.after(1000, newz)
```

inside function `newz`

Something like this

```
#--- newz - start ---
def newz():
    url = 'https://news.google.com/rss?hl=ja&gl=JP&ceid=JP:ja'
    d = feedparser.parse(url)
    news = list()

    for i, entry in enumerate(d.entries, 1):
        p = entry.published_parsed
        sortkey = "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d" % (p.tm_year, p.tm_mon, p.tm_mday, p.tm_hour, p.tm_min, p.tm_sec)

        tmp = {
            "title": entry.title,
        #"link": entry.link,
            "sortkey": sortkey
            }

        news.append(tmp)

    news = sorted(news, key=lambda x: x['sortkey'])

    myDict = {}

    for d in news:
        c = d['title']
        myDict[c] = myDict.get(c,0)+1
        frequency = myDict.keys()
    frequency = list(frequency)
    for x in range(len(frequency)):
        print(frequency[x])
        source.config(text=str(frequency[x]))
        x += 1

    #source.config(text="some text")
    root.after(1000, newz) # 1000ms = 1s
#--- newz - end ---
```

Comment: I would like to display `(frequency[x])` and each time call the next index (x) - next value -from the frequency list

Comment: I added `source.config(text=str(frequency[x]))` near `print()` but it will run very fast so you will see only last value.

Comment: Could I add there `.sleep()`?

Comment: sleep will freeze window - when you run sleep (or other long-running function) then `mainloop` can't get mouse/keyboard events from system, can't update values in widgets, can't redraw window. And it can't run `after()` so it will stop clock.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks for the advices, gonna try to handle it somehow

Comment: you could create one string with all frequences and display all at once. Or you can keep frequences on global list (now it is local list) and create other function which put new frequence in label and run `after()` to change text after some seconds.